# Non-standard named non-unique foreign keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Due to the way that my database is set up (which I don't have control over), I've got a foreign key situation that I can't figure out in Entity Framework.  I'm using Fluent API to configure my relationships.  My classes are

```
public class Parent
{
   // Unique primary key
   public int PrimaryKey { get; set; }

   // These two fields together compose the foreign key to join to Child
   public string ParentForeignKey1 { get; set; }
   public string ParentForeignKey2 { get; set; }

   public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
   // Unique primary key
   public int PrimaryKey { get; set; }

   // These two fields together compose the (non-unique) foreign key to join to Parent
   public string ChildForeignKey1 { get; set; }
   public string ChildForeignKey2 { get; set; }

   // The parent/child relationship is implicit, even though the tables
   // themselves indicate a many-to-many relationship
   public List<Parent> Parents { get; set; }
}
```

The Entity Framework relationship should be such that the two tables join on the `ParentForeignKey` and `ChildForeignKey` fields like

```
SELECT * 
FROM Parent 
JOIN Child 
 ON  Child.ChildForeignKey1 = Parent.ParentForeignKey1
 AND Child.ChildForeignKey2 = Parent.ParentForeignKey2
```

How do I set up the Fluent API foreign key mapping so that Entity Framework generates those joins when I query the `DbSet`s?

Comment: You have only one Parent.  Shouldn't you have a List<Parent> someplace in the code?

Comment: Good point.  I'll update the question.  I didn't put that in because the parent/child relationship is implicit (there will only be one parent per child, even though the SQL join is actually a many-to-many).

Answer (score 0):

I think this makes more sense

```
public class Parent
{
   // The parent/child relationship is implicit, even though the tables
   // themselves indicate a many-to-many relationship
   public static List<Parent> Parents { get; set; }


   // Unique primary key
   public int PrimaryKey { get; set; }

   // These two fields together compose the foreign key to join to Child
   public string ParentForeignKey1 { get; set; }
   public string ParentForeignKey2 { get; set; }

   public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
   // Unique primary key
   public int PrimaryKey { get; set; }

   // These two fields together compose the (non-unique) foreign key to join to Parent
   public string ChildForeignKey1 { get; set; }
   public string ChildForeignKey2 { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: What does putting the static property in `Parent` do?

Comment: Creates a single common List<> object for every instance of the Parent Class.  The two classes represent you final results.  Where does the child class inputs come from?  The Children in the Parent class is a link, but you have no input List<> of Child.  I think you also need a static Child List<>

Comment: Maybe I was unclear in my original question.  I want to know how to set the foreign key relationships (`...HasForeignKey()...`) so that when Entity Framework generates SQL to join `Parent` to `Child` (from a LINQ statement) it joins the tables like I have in my example.

Comment: You need two lists as inputs.  Where are the input lists?